# PHPUnit tests not executed

Tags: phpunit

All tests of the following class are executed correctly:

```
namespace AppTest;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ConfigTest extends TestCase
{
    const VALID_CONFIG = [
        'file'  => '/etc/files/test.conf',
        'other' => Sub\OtherConfigTest::VALID_CONFIG
    ];

    public function testValidation()
    {
        // some tests and assertions, everything executed correctly
    }
}
```

Any tests inside *Sub\OtherConfigTest*, however, are not executed at all:

```
namespace AppTest\Sub;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class OtherConfigTest extends TestCase
{
    const VALID_CONFIG = [
        'ip' => '192.168.1.1'
    ];

    public function testValidation()
    {
        // not called at all
    }
}
```

If I change the constant definition in the first class, replacing `Sub\OtherConfigTest::VALID_CONFIG` by the actual array `['ip' => '192.168.1.1']`, all tests are executed.

May this be a bug in PHPUnit or is it expected behavior?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "replacing Sub\OtherConfigTest::VALID_CONFIG by the actual array." Can you provide that example as well, please? Also, are there any error messages reported when you run the tests?

Comment: @user866762 I meant replacing `Sub\OtherConfigTest::VALID_CONFIG` by `['ip' => '192.168.1.1']` in class _AppTest\ConfigTest_.